# How to use Echo Dot as a microphone?

Tags: mac, iphone

My goal is to utilize an Echo Dot(3rd gen) as a microphone.

However, I have yet to find a straightforward method to achieve this. My current best solution is to the "drop in" feature on the Echo Dot, which results in the audio recorded by the Echo Dot being broadcast through my phone's speaker(drop basically create an internet call between echo and phone). However, this approach presents a challenge as I can't figure out a way to capture and process that audio (coming out of my phone) on my MacBook. I assumed this wouldn’t be too hard, as it is the idea as trying to record for example a phone call on your MacBook.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to record audio from an Echo Dot directly?
2. If the above isn't feasible, what method can I use to transfer the audio from my phone to my Mac so that I can manipulate it using a Python script? (Similar to the idea of recording a phone call from your phone onto your Mac for later processing).

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://soundscapehq.com/use-echo-dot-as-computer-speaker/

Comment: Hello, what's the Echo Dot version?

Comment: I tried following that guide but ran into several problems. The first is that the echo dot 3rd gen aux is output only(https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/i7smt7/3rd_gen_echo_dot_aux_audio/), as far as I can tell, and can't be used for input. The second is that when connecting via bluetooth, I can't see the device as an input option, only output. I tried seeing if I could change this under both sound settings and MIDI settings, but that was not possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Destroy666, I should've included that in the question. Its an echo dot 3rd gen.

Comment: I wonder what version of the echo dot they were using in the blog. It was written April this year, so maybe it’s a newer version of the dot?

Comment: Have you tried on both windows and Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This is the subject of the post
[Is it possible to use Amazon Echo as a normal bluetooth microphone for a PC?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/639/is-it-possible-to-use-amazon-echo-as-a-normal-bluetooth-microphone-for-a-pc)

Here is the accepted
[answer by Helmar](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/645) :

> Nope.
>
> There are currently just two Bluetooth profiles supported.
>
> > **Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)**      This profile allows you to stream audio from your mobile device (such as a phone or
> > tablet) to Echo.
>
> > **Audio / Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)**  This profile allows you to use hands-free voice control when a mobile device is connected
> > to your Echo.
>
> ([Amazon Support
> Page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201727450))

Comment: This might be out of date. See my comment on the original post

Comment: Also the question has a follow up if the answer is no. Where the poster wants to know if it’s not possible (which I think it might be, suggesting that this answer is out of date, but if it’s not out of date) then can they use some form of recording software to record audio from their phone to their MacBook, similar to the idea of recording a phone call from your Mac. Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: However, since A2DP works, I was thinking that I could stream audio to my mobile device, and then get that audio into my mac, to be processed later(as explained in the post). I just haven't been able to record calls from my phone to mac, only general audio(such as music or voice memos)

Comment: Also, I don't need to use it as a bluetooth microphone. The echo can output audio via aux, which I could record on a computer.

Comment: @Tim: Apparently the designers of the Echo didn't plan it for that purpose.